# Custom Font not working properly in Emails?

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, custom-font

I have received a font, I uploaded the ttf given in a server with a public route accessible publicly via any browser.

I found a client who used same approach before but the solution was working for them, not for me, but they used woff instead of ttf, so I used the ttf format anf ttf file obviously.

```
@font-face { 
   font-family: 'TEST'; 
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 300;
   src: local('TEST'), local('TEST'), url('https://publicurl/fonts/longines/myfontcalledBison.ttf') format('ttf');
}
```

And I used :

```
<span style="font-family: 'TEST'; "></span>
```

So same solution worked with one font, but did not work for an other. Knowing  that both fonts are custom.

Also I converted my ttf file to woff using CloudConvert App and tried again :

```
@font-face { 
       font-family: 'TEST'; 
       font-style: normal;
       font-weight: 300;
       src: local('TEST'), local('TEST'), url('https://publicurl/fonts/longines/myfontcalledBison.woff') format('woff');
    }
```

But same thing.

Solution not working even in web browser.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the console log say anything? Often there's an issue with CORS

Comment: you can use this site if it's easier: https://parcel.io/tools/cors-check

Comment: The route returning the font is allowing all

Comment: You use a font-weight of 300. Does the font have that weight? Normal is 400, so 300 would be a 'light' version. To test that you'd have to specify `<span style="font-family: 'TEST';font-weight:300 ">`